# String_Split multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, apply

I need to split values of two columns in a table with separated values.

My source table looks like:

| product_id | ean_upc | is_approved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2102961 | 8710103368021;8710103368038;8710103368014 | 1;0;1 |
| 92923683 | 0195161923722;195161923722;10195161923729 | 1;1;0 |
| 656364 | 8710103203919;8710103239093;8710103203902 | 1;1;1 |
| 735699 | 8710103285885;8710103295938;8710103295952 | 0;0;1 |

What I need is a select statement that give me back each `product_id` and `EAN` code

```
SELECT 
    product_id, EAN.value
FROM
    IceCatUK.dbo.ice_indexCSV_tmp
CROSS APPLY
    STRING_SPLIT(ean_upc , ';') EAN
```

The problem is that I need to have the `is_approved` information too.

My final table needs to have `Product_id`, the separated `EAN_upc` and the `is_approved` flag.

The `is_approved` must be linked to the columns of the EAN

The result for the first line should look like this:

| product_id | ean_upc | is_approved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2102961 | 8710103368021 | 1 |
| 2102961 | 8710103368038 | 0 |
| 2102961 | 8710103368014 | 1 |

How to link the position in the `string_split(EAN)` with the position of `string_split("is_approved")` ?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: By far the best solution to this problem would be to stop storing delimited values. It violates 1NF and is nothing but painful to work with. Of course we don't always have that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to @lemon's excellent answer, but gathering both EAN and APPROVED into separate result sets and joining on both `product_id` and `ordinal` to avoid the potentially large intermediate cartesian result set that is produced by two joins of Cross-Apply. Depending on the size of your data, this may be more performant.

```
SELECT ice_indexCSV_tmp.product_id, 
  EAN.value as ean_upc,
  dt.is_approved
FROM ice_indexCSV_tmp
   CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ean_upc, ';', 1) EAN
   INNER JOIN 
       ( 
            SELECT ice.product_id, APPROVED.value as is_approved, APPROVED.ordinal 
            FROM ice_indexCSV_tmp ice 
                CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(is_approved, ';', 1) APPROVED 
      ) dt
     ON EAN.ordinal = dt.ordinal
        AND ice_indexCSV_tmp.product_id = dt.product_id
```

[dbfiddle version](https://dbfiddle.uk/aNdvM5RY)

Note that the [`enable_ordinal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#enable_ordinal) parameter is only available in sql-server 2022 16.x or Azure databases. A terrible oversight that it wasn't included when `string_split()` was initially rolled out.

The `row_number` route in @charleschen's answer is likely the next best option, but because there is no guarantee about the order of the values spit out by the cross-apply and `string_split()` it's a bit of a gamble. That being said, I've never seen SQL Server spit out `string_split` results in a different order than the string that was fed into it.

ULTIMATELY, if I had an older version of sql-server where the `enable_ordinal` was not available, and this was production level code,  I would probably look to pre-processing the source data that was used to populate this table before ingesting into sql server. You could make quick work of this in a pandas dataframe with [`pandas.Series.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html).

Comment: Great Job! Works fine.

Comment: As you expected - it is much faster @lemon's code ... you made my day ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Beginning from SQL Server 2022, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` with the third parameter set to 1 to catch ordinality of the strings being split into rows. Then you can filter on matching ordinalities.

```
SELECT tab.product_id,
       single_ean_upc.value AS ean_upc,
       single_is_approved.value AS is_approved
FROM tab
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tab.ean_upc, ';', 1) AS single_ean_upc
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tab.is_approved, ';', 1) AS single_is_approved
WHERE single_ean_upc.ordinal =  single_is_approved.ordinal
```

**Output**:

| product_id | ean_upc | is_approved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2102961 | 8710103368021 | 1 |
| 2102961 | 8710103368038 | 0 |
| 2102961 | 8710103368014 | 1 |
| 92923683 | 0195161923722 | 1 |
| 92923683 | 195161923722 | 1 |
| 92923683 | 10195161923729 | 0 |
| 656364 | 8710103203919 | 1 |
| 656364 | 8710103239093 | 1 |
| 656364 | 8710103203902 | 1 |
| 735699 | 8710103285885 | 0 |
| 735699 | 8710103295938 | 0 |
| 735699 | 8710103295952 | 1 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1S4BB2J2).

Comment: Please read the [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=column%20is%20disabled.-,Note,-The%20enable_ordinal%20argument) when you are not on "Azure SQL Database", or on a SQL Server before version 2022.

Comment: You're right, it's probably more correct to specify the version from which this works.

Answer (score 1):

You need an ordinal position to join on in order to guarantee the correct values are joined together. In SQL Server 2022+ String_Split supports an ordinal position however prior to that, you have to roll your own; you simply cannot rely on artificially adding a row number against a set which by definition is unordered.

If you don't have a suitable function I include one below.

Using a defined sequence you can then do:

```
with ean as (
    select Product_Id, Part Ean_UPC, Seq
    from t
    cross apply dbo.stringsplit(Ean_Upc)
), a as (
    select Product_Id, Part Is_Approved, Seq
    from t
    cross apply dbo.stringsplit(Is_Approved)
)
select ean.Product_Id, ean.Ean_UPC, a.Is_Approved
from ean join a on ean.Product_Id = a.Product_Id and ean.Seq = a.Seq;
```

String split function:

```
create or alter function dbo.StringSplit(@String Varchar(100))
returns Table with schemabinding as
return
with 
    t1(n) as (select n from(values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))n(n)), 
    t2(n) as (select 1 from t1 x cross join t1 y), /* 100 rows for 100 chars */
    t(n) as (select top (IsNull(DataLength(@string), 0)) Row_Number() over (order by (select 1/0)) from t2),
    s(n1) as (
        select 1 
        union all
        select t.n + 1 
        from t
        where Substring(@string, t.n, 1) =';' /* Return start positions for each part in string */
    ),
    pos as (select n1, IsNull(Lead(n1) over(order by n1), 100) nxt from s)
select part, 
    Row_Number() over(order by n1) Seq
from pos
cross apply(values(Substring(@string, n1, nxt - n1 - 1)))w(part)
where DataLength(part) > 0;
```

Demo [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zS5phq9b)

Answer (score 1):

Just another option if not 2022.  This will be supported by  2016+

Note: Provided your data consistency, the `string_escape( ..., 'json')` could be trimmed out.

**Example**

```
Select A.product_id
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select [ean_upc]     = B1.Value
                    ,[is_approved] = B2.Value
               From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape([ean_upc],'json'),';','","')+'"]' ) B1
               Join  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape([is_approved],'json'),';','","')+'"]' ) B2
               On B1.[Key]=B2.[Key]
             ) B
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: This approach looks quite clean. Would you say this is faster than JNevill's?

Comment: @lemon I suspect his would be a nudge more performant using the built-in function provided you've got the latest version

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way using `string_split` and `inner join` :

```
select ean.product_id, ean.ean_upc, i.is_approved
from (
  select e.product_id, value as ean_upc, ordinal
  from mytable e
  Cross Apply string_split(ean_upc, ';', 1) b
  where e.product_id = 2102961
) as ean
INNER JOIN (
  select product_id, value as is_approved, ordinal
  from mytable
  Cross Apply string_split(is_approved,';', 1) b
  where product_id = 2102961
) as i on i.product_id = ean.product_id and i.ordinal = ean.ordinal
```

Result :

```
product_id  ean_upc         is_approved
2102961     8710103368021   1
2102961     8710103368038   0
2102961     8710103368014   1
```

Starting from SQL Server 2022, the `STRING_SPLIT()` function supports an optional third parameter to enable_ordinal.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VFUNXodE)

Answer (score -2):

To link the position in the `string_split` function for EAN with the position of `string_split` for `is_approved`, you can make use of the `ROW_NUMBER` function to assign a row number to each element in both separate values. Then you can join the results based on the row number, like this:

```sql
WITH EAN_CTE AS (
    SELECT product_id, value AS ean, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM IceCatUK.dbo.ice_indexCSV_tmp
    CROSS APPLY string_split(ean_upc, ';')
), Approved_CTE AS (
    SELECT product_id, value AS is_approved, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM IceCatUK.dbo.ice_indexCSV_tmp
    CROSS APPLY string_split(is_approved, ';')
)
SELECT EAN_CTE.product_id, EAN_CTE.ean, Approved_CTE.is_approved
FROM EAN_CTE
JOIN Approved_CTE ON EAN_CTE.product_id = Approved_CTE.product_id AND EAN_CTE.rn = Approved_CTE.rn
```

This query uses Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to assign row numbers to the separated values of `ean_upc` and `is_approved` using the `ROW_NUMBER` function. Then it joins the two CTEs based on the `product_id` and the row number (`rn`) to link the corresponding elements together.

This way, the result will include the `product_id`, the separated `ean_upc`, and the corresponding `is_approved` flag for each entry.

Comment: The reason for the downvotes here is that Microsoft doesn't guarantee that the elements in the `STRING_SPLIT` function will be in the same order on every execution. That means that this code is non-deterministic and could result in bad linking between elements. TLDR; this will _look_ like it worked, but could break your data.